# FatalErrorException in routes.php line 51: Class 'app\Game' not found laravel 5.1

Tags: php, model, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-routing

This is my `Game.php` model class code which resides in `app` directory

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Game extends Model
{

}
```

and in my `routes.php`

```
<?php 
use app\Game; 
Route::get('game',function(){

    $game = new app\Game;
    $game->name = 'Assassins Creed';
    $game->description = 'Assassins VS templars.';
    $game->save();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to have Capital A in App\Game?

Comment: thanks , it worked but why is it so?? directory name is `app` not `App`.

Comment: It's not about the directory name. It's the namespace. namespace App;
It's saying, using the Game class in the App namespace